# Console in lower pane that catch syntax errors

Tags: xul

While creating an extension in Firefox, I'd like to have real web console at the bottom of the screen.
I tried Firebug's console but it doesn't catch syntax errors, and the other ones I tried do not catch these either.
I also tried to put the webconsole.xul into an iframe into my own xul file. The console appears, but it is not working.

```
<iframe src="chrome://browser/content/devtools/webconsole.xul" flex="1"/>
```

I guess this could have been expected. Is there a way to have a console in the lower pane that catch JavaScript syntax errors, as the Browser Console does ?

Answer (score 0):

I took the erroneous assumption that Firebug can't catch syntax errors, since I couldn't catch them myself with the "onerror" event handler.

I just had to check "Show Chrome Errors" in the console options of Firebug.